# Realtion between model.parameters() and nn.Embedding()

Tags: parameters, pytorch, lookup, embedding

I have the code here

```py
import torch


class Model(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num, dim):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.node_embed = torch.nn.Embedding(num, dim)

def update_node_embed(B):

    first_ten_embed = B[0:10] # it raise error that B is not callable
    first_ten_embed *= 0.1


A = model(1000, 16)
B = list(A.parameters())
```

As we know `B` will contain the 'weight' of `self.node_embed`. The function `update_node_embed` will take `B` as input, and I need to update the lookup table `self.node_embed`.

My question is that How can I get `self.node_embed` from `B`? I try but it told me that `B` is parameters and is not callable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter within `A.parameters()` is your embedding.
Here is your `update_node_embed()`:

```
def update_node_embed(B):
    embed_params = B[0]
    first_ten_embed = embed_params[:10]
    with torch.no_grad(): # Avoid in-place operation on a leaf variable
        first_ten_embed *= 0.1
```